# netdb.h not linking properly

Tags: c, networking, linker

I'm trying to compile this program, as referenced in *Beej's Guide to Network Programming* on page 19.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int main() {
    int status;
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *servinfo;          /* Will point to the results */
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);    /* Make sure the struct is empty */
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;        /* Don't care IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if ((status = getaddrinfo(NULL, "3490", &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo error: %s\n", gai_strerror(status));
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Servinfo now points to a linked list of 1 or more struct addrinfos
        ... do everything until you don't need servinfo anymore .... */

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); /* Free the linked-list */

    return 0;
}
```

Among other errors, I see

```
../main.c:8:18: error: storage size of ‘hints’ isn’t known
../main.c:13:19: error: ‘AI_PASSIVE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../main.c:16:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gai_strerror’
```

It appears that gcc isn't linking with `netdb.h`. Eclipse, the IDE that I'm using to build this, has no trouble finding the file. Here's the compiler command:

```
gcc -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -ansi -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o"main.o" "../main.c"
```

Adding `-lnetdb` doesn't resolve the issue. Also...

```
~> find /usr/include/ -name netdb.h
/usr/include/bits/netdb.h
/usr/include/gssrpc/netdb.h
/usr/include/netdb.h
/usr/include/rpc/netdb.h
```

I think these files came preinstalled on my openSUSE host. Why doesn't gcc detect `netdb.h`? Or am I drawing the wrong conclusion?

Comment: I am running into a similar issue on Linux Mint 20. My IDE (VS Code) doesn't recognize the addrinfo struct and when compiling I get the following errors:

gethost.c: In function ‘main’:
gethost.c:52:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘freehostent’; did you mean 
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccNUFQ8z.o: in function `main':
gethost.c:(.text+0x2ad): undefined reference to `freehostent'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

This exact same source file compiles fine on MacOS 10.14.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ```
> ../main.c:8:18: error: storage size of ‘hints’ isn’t known
> ../main.c:13:19: error: ‘AI_PASSIVE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
> ../main.c:16:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gai_strerror’
> ```
>
> It appears that gcc isn't linking with netdb.h....

These are not linking errors, and you don't need a netdb shared object
file (there is no such beast; `netdb.h` simply defines data structures
and macros for use in your code).

These are compiler errors: gcc complaining because you're using names
that it doesn't recognize (`AI_PASSIVE`) and data types for which the
structure is unknown (`struct addrinfo`).

The code as you've presented it appears to be correct, and `addrinfo`
is defined in `/usr/include/netdb.h`.  What happens if you compile it
like this:

```
gcc -c main.c
```

Do you still get the same behavior? If so, take a look at the output
of:

```
gcc -E main.c
```

This generates a preprocessed version of the code, with all of the
`#include` statements replaced by their actual content.  You should be
able to grep through this and see if the compiler is actually getting
`/usr/include/netdb.h` if if it's finding something else:

```
$ gcc -E foo.c | grep netdb.h | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u
```

Which on my system yields:

```
"/usr/include/bits/netdb.h"
"/usr/include/netdb.h"
"/usr/include/rpc/netdb.h"
```

When you add `-ansi` to the command line, your are changing the way
`gcc` behaves in ways that will break the Linux kernel and many system
header files.  The `addrinfo` definition in `netdb.h` is protected
like this:

```
#ifdef  __USE_POSIX
/* Structure to contain information about address of a service provider.  */
struct addrinfo
{
  int ai_flags;                 /* Input flags.  */
  int ai_family;                /* Protocol family for socket.  */
  int ai_socktype;              /* Socket type.  */
  int ai_protocol;              /* Protocol for socket.  */
  socklen_t ai_addrlen;         /* Length of socket address.  */
  struct sockaddr *ai_addr;     /* Socket address for socket.  */
  char *ai_canonname;           /* Canonical name for service location.  */
  struct addrinfo *ai_next;     /* Pointer to next in list.  */
};

// ...other stuff...
#endif
```

When you run `gcc` with the `-ansi` flag, this undefines the
`__USE_POSIX` macro, because things protected by this may not be
strictly ANSI compliant.  You can see the difference if you compare
this:

```
gcc -E /usr/include/netdb.h
```

With this:

```
gcc -E -ansi /usr/include/netdb.h
```

Only the former contains the `addrinfo` structure.

Comment: I get the same three header files as output. I see these compile errors: http://pastebin.com/jVVMqftA

Comment: So...it's working?  That is, you're not seeing any errors related to `netdb.h`, and you're just getting a warning about `memset()`?  That sounds like progress.  The `memset()` warning means you need to `#include <string.h>` (this comes from the `memset(3)` man page).

Comment: I don't see any warnings or errors if I include `string.h` as well. However, I want my code to be ANSI C-compliant so I'm still getting these errors... http://pastebin.com/B21NyGQ9

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain what's happening.  If you've found this discussion helpful, indicating so by accepting the answer would be very kind.

Answer (score 3):

add at the top of your file

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. The problem was the presence of this line: `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309` and adding `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600` immediately underneath it fixed it, without having to remove it entirely or change it to `_GNU_SOURCE` which would have changed the meaning of the program too much.

Answer (score 0):

Linking doesn't attach a header file to the program, pre-processing handles header files.

Linking attaches shared object libraries (look in /usr/lib) to compiled objects.  Sometimes it is not sufficent to just add "-lnetdb" as the library might not be in the linker path.  In that case, you need to use a -L(path) to add a path entry so the directive "-lnetdb" can find the correct netdb.so file.

Comment: It looks like I don't have a shared object named `*netdb*` in that folder... http://pastebin.com/9GPmFehC How can I obtain the SO files that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use `#include <netinet/in.h>` ....along with that.....and in compilation (ubuntu)....

```
gcc server/client -o server/client.c -lpthread
```

(here `lpthread` is a linki processing thread)...which solves your problem.  :-D